# Retrieving jsonp data with callback function

Tags: 8

I need to call a service to retrieve the available values for a select in a form I am creating. Therefore, I need to do this in the .module file and load the options with an array of items that I received from the service.

I retrieve that results but due to it having a callback function, I cannot seem to iterate through the data to retrieve only certain values from the data.

I have the following.

```
$request = drupal_http_request('http://[local]/TemplateManager/GetRenderingStrategies?Wizard=false&callback=jsonCallback');
```

I get back this.

```
jsonCallback([
{
    "HTMLRenderingStrategyId": 1,
    "IsEnabled": true,
    "CreatedDate": "2013-04-19T10:30:36.563",
    "CreatedBy": 1,
    "UpdatedDate": "2013-04-19T10:30:36.563",
    "UpdatedBy": 1,
    "RowGuid": "19223fcf-45c2-452b-aac6-ba357169ff26",
    "Name": "DEFAULT",
    "FormTemplateView": "/Templates/Default/FormTemplate.cshtml",
    "ManagedChoiceTemplateView": null,
    "NoMatchTemplateView": null,
    "ThankYouTemplateView": null,
    "NoThankYouTemplateView": null,
    "CSSPath": "/Templates/Default/css/Base.css",
    "CrossSellTemplateView": null,
    "CrossSellMaxProgramsToDisplay": null
},
{
    "HTMLRenderingStrategyId": 2,
    "IsEnabled": true,
    "CreatedDate": "2013-04-19T10:30:36.563",
    "CreatedBy": 1,
    "UpdatedDate": "2013-04-19T10:30:36.563",
    "UpdatedBy": 1,
    "RowGuid": "2ea1ecb7-0281-4361-87ee-d4cfe12c9b0c",
    "Name": "EMD",
    "FormTemplateView": "/Templates/EMD/FormTemplate.cshtml",
    "ManagedChoiceTemplateView": null,
    "NoMatchTemplateView": null,
    "ThankYouTemplateView": null,
    "NoThankYouTemplateView": null,
    "CSSPath": "/Templates/EMD/css/Base.css",
    "CrossSellTemplateView": null,
    "CrossSellMaxProgramsToDisplay": null
},
{
    "HTMLRenderingStrategyId": 3,
    "IsEnabled": true,
    "CreatedDate": "2013-04-19T10:30:36.563",
    "CreatedBy": 1,
    "UpdatedDate": "2013-04-19T10:30:36.563",
    "UpdatedBy": 1,
    "RowGuid": "e2d7ed2e-7ed7-4d2e-aecb-0a589c7ad338",
    "Name": "ELEARNERS",
    "FormTemplateView": "/Templates/eLearners/FormTemplate.cshtml",
    "ManagedChoiceTemplateView": null,
    "NoMatchTemplateView": null,
    "ThankYouTemplateView": null,
    "NoThankYouTemplateView": null,
    "CSSPath": "/Templates/eLearners/css/Base.css",
    "CrossSellTemplateView": "/Templates/eLearners/CrossSellTemplate.cshtml",
    "CrossSellMaxProgramsToDisplay": 10
}]);
```

What is my next step to pull out only the "Name" from the result set?

I am at a loss here. I tried looking for the answer and it seems all the jsonp calls are done in javascript/jQuery and that doesn't really suit me.

If you feel I am doing this incorrectly, please let me know. I have never worked with jsonp or json and Drupal for that matter.

Comment: you want to get Name from the result set using php or javascript/jQuery?

Comment: First off, thank you for answering my question. I want to use php.  For some reason i cannot access the data.

Comment: question: why use jsonp with php? just use json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom function called `jsonp_decode` with one argument to convert **JSONP** format to **JSON** format and return decoded **JSON**

```
function jsonp_decode($jsonp) {
  $jsonp = preg_replace('/^.*?\(/', "", $jsonp);
  $jsonp = preg_replace('/\);\s*$/', "", $jsonp);
  return drupal_json_decode($jsonp);
}
```

Then you can pull the "Name" from the result set as the following code:

```
$request = drupal_http_request('http://[local]/TemplateManager/GetRenderingStrategies?Wizard=false&callback=jsonCallback');

$names = array();

$items = jsonp_decode($request);

foreach($items as $item) {
  $names[] = $item['Name'];
}

var_dump($names);
```